# Refactor if with exit from programm to one line

Tags: php, if-statement, refactoring, code-cleanup

Inside my funciton I check if password/email are valid.
I do it like this:

```
if ( ! Password::isSafe())
{
     print Password::getSafetyError();

     return;
}
```

If password is correct - I move on function code. If not - I exit from function with return and print userError;


Can I do it one line only?
It would be good not to use Exceptions, cause Global ExceptionHandler write exceptions to log, and this way I will need to filter typical user errors inside this ExceptionHandler.

Comment: I don't see any `else` here

Comment: really strange...

Answer (score 1):

You can simply put the code on one line, but this does not improve clarity. At a code review, the only issue I'd bring up is the blank line in the body -- needless vertical whitespace makes code harder to read. Also, the spaces around the `!` are better removed for clarity. It's good to try improve your code 'locally', but in this case I don't see what you are concerned about.

Comment: Is it works this way? I thought ternary just return not execute what is inside brackets...

Comment: can you add a code? What I exactly need: if statement is true - move on, if false - stop programm execution

Comment: I've tried ternary - I have no result like in question

Comment: My apologies, my previous answer was irrelevant so I removed it.

Comment: I am not concerned. Just try to find ways make code better that I have not admitted by myself. Yep, I can just write it one line, but may be PHP has simplified ways to do it. I just asked. Gratefull to you, comrad, anyway